# Cannot override Magento Newsletter module template on my theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to override this Magento 2.3 template:

`vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml`

So in my theme, I created the corresponding file ([as explained on the docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-walkthrough.html)):

`app/design/frontend/ComSpirit/Optonet/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml`

I cleared the cache and static files... But Magento doesn't show my changes!
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that your frontend is configured to use your custom theme *'ComSpirit/Optonet'* under *Content > Design > Configuration*.
2. If point 1 doesn't help, make sure that the mentioned template *(vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml)* is really used on storefront. Add some text to the template, flush cache and refresh the page. If the text doesn't appear on storefront, then probably a 3rd party module is overwriting the template with another one.

Comment: I already did those steps but Magento doesn't load the template in `app/design/frontend/ComSpirit/Optonet/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml.` I flushed the cache and checked for third party modules... It uses `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml` still